# How to insert text into a file using web input forms?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple text file that needs to be updated on a regular basis.  Instead of cutting and pasting the new data, I'd like to have a web input form where I can just enter the new info, and it will update the text file.  For example, I may enter a new "Headline", or "URL", and I'd want that string to be inserted into the correct place in the file.

What's the easiest way for me to do this?  The file doesn't have to be saved, I can copy and paste the text file after it generates the new text.

### For example, the text that I would want updated looks like this:

[Headline]

### the above sentence is the headline and this is the [URL]

There would be 2 web input forms.  1 for Headline, 1 for URL.   When I enter text into the input, the javascript would insert it into the correct place in the textarea.  Then I can just copy and paste that text into whatever I needed.  This is a very simple script, I just have no idea how to build it.

Comment: Have you made an attempt at it with a script we can see?

Comment: What is the format of the file?

Comment: No, because I don't know enough javascript to do it.  I was hoping someone can point me to an example, and then I would just hack it to make it work for myself

Comment: The file can be just plain text

Comment: You will have to do it in PHP, and you still won't be able to save the file. Wouldn't it be easier to just, you know, open the file? :)

Answer (score 0):

Web browser scripting can't access the file system.